# Using a cell reference entered into a cell?

Tags: vba, excel

In cell K1 VBA inserts a cell reference that changes based on certain conditions outlined in the vba code.

For this example lets say the value of this cell is $A$13

Now in cell K2 I want it to equal what ever is in cell reference provided by K1.

So in other words how do I use the cell reference provided in cell K1 in excel formulas because when ever I press =K1 I receive the value of the cell i.e. $A$13 and not the value of cell $A$13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the function `INDIRECT()`

```
=INDIRECT(K1)
```

Please note this however: `INDIRECT()` is a volatile function, meaning that it will recalculating more often than necessary because of the uncertainty of the reference. For lighter workbooks this poses no problem. However, for more complex, heavier workbooks this can heavily slow the calculations. I have seen workbooks take 3-4+ minutes to open only to take ~5 seconds to open after eliminating all calls to `INDIRECT()`.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentleman